# Value keeps resetting in method

Tags: java, methods

This should be a quite simple problem, but since im quite new to programming I cant seem to figure it out.
I want to count the seats that are available in a restaurant and substract the amount of free seats after every new reservation (places order).

I have set the starting value for 'restaurantCapacity' to 10 but it resets back to 10 after every new group. How do i overwrite this value.
The problem should be in the method 'seatCapacity'

If the code works correctly it should have 1 seat remaining. (10 - group of 4 - group of 5= 1)

```
public class Reservation {
  int guestCount;
  int restaurantCapacity =10;
  boolean isRestaurantOpen;
  boolean isConfirmed;

//Constructor
  public Reservation(int groupSize, boolean restaurantStatus){
    guestCount = groupSize;
    isRestaurantOpen = restaurantStatus;
    //Order not filled
    if (isRestaurantOpen == false || guestCount > restaurantCapacity){
      System.out.println("Sorry, we were not able to fill your order.");
      //Reason
      if(isRestaurantOpen == false){
        System.out.println("We are currently closed.");
      }
      else{
        System.out.println("We are out of seats.\n");
      }
      isConfirmed = false;
    }
    //Succesfull Order
    else{
      System.out.println("Your order has been filled");
      isConfirmed = true;
    }
  }

//Number of free seats------------------------------------
//METHOD WITH THE PROBLEM!

  public void seatCapacity(boolean isConfirmed){
    if (isConfirmed == true){
      System.out.println(restaurantCapacity); //----VALUE STAYS AT 10??
      restaurantCapacity -= guestCount;
      System.out.println(guestCount + " seats have been taken. " + restaurantCapacity + " seats are remaining.\n");
      }
    }

//Main
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Reservation mason = new Reservation(4, true);
    mason.seatCapacity(true);
    Reservation johnson = new Reservation(5, true);
    johnson.seatCapacity(true);
  }
}
```

I have tried a bunch of stuff but it keeps resetting every time.
I dont know if anyone will see this but help would be super appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: As the current answerers have pointed out, you seem to have a bit of a misunderstanding on how to model this properly with you class. If you think about how a reservation in the real world works, you wouldn't say that a particular reservation any bearing on a restaurant's total capacity (modeled here by `restaurantCapacity`), this would instead be a property of the restaurant itself. Similar logic could be applied to the idea of if the restaurant is open (`isRestaurantOpen`).

Comment: Hi. I am still experimenting and changing things with this code, but got stuck with this problem. Thank you for your advice. I will try to adjust it the way you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see, `restaurantCapacity` is an atribute of the class `Reservation`, which means that each instance will have its own variable `restaurantCapacity`. So, when you create `mason` and `johnson`, each one has its own variable, with separate values of 10 (and to which 4 and 5 are substracted, respectively).

If you want a variable **to be shared across instances of the same class**, you have to declare it static. Try to add `static` before the declaration of the attribute you want to be shared.

```java
static int restaurantCapacity = 10;
```

Comment: This is crazy. I just joined this website and i did not expect to get several answers within minutes. I probably should havbe known the answer to this problem but i am very thankful for the explanation. <3

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to make the restaurantCapacity `static`, that way it will be shared between instances of `Reservation`.

I would advise however for you to look into modelling an object for the Restaurant itself. The Reservation is doing a bit too much right now and the Restaurant could be in charge of it's own capacity and determining whether a reservation was accepted or not.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same thing, adding a Resturant model, as the capacity should be taken out from Reservation. Perhaps, along with the capacity, the Resutant object may have also a List of reservations. Anyway, good one!

Comment: Btw, even if it could solve the issue, I don't actually see the capacity as static member of reservation, I see it as a workaround for the specific class modeling, but i'm not so fond of it.

Comment: Thank you your answer. I was also thinking that my constructor was pretty cluttered. I will try to put your advice into action.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a variable stay with his old value making it static will help you.

```
static int restaurantCapacity = 10;
```

is enough for you.